# Numeric UpDown Control for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Can any one Please provide Numeric UpDown Control demo with Xamarin Forms
Does this control Available in Xamarin Forms?
thanks
Prashanth

Answer (score 8):

See edit #2.

<s>No there is not a spinner control out-of-the-box. If you do not want to get creative, you could use the `Picker` control and insert predefined values into it. `Picker` info [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/).</s>

Otherwise it would be pretty trivial to create an up and down `Button` and an `Entry` or `Label`. Clicking the up `Button` increments a number in the `Entry` or `Label`. Clicking the down `Button` decrements a number in the `Entry` or `Label`.

*Edit: Just happened to land on Syncfusion's [NumericUpDown](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/numericupdown) control which does want you want. You can also get a free community license for the control if you are a lone developer or a group of 5 or fewer people. Community License info [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense)

*Edit #2: Was looking through the Xamarin Views list page [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/controls/views/) and saw that actually do have a `Stepper` control now!

Comment: @PrashanthR See edit for new example if you did not like the other two examples

Comment: hey thanks for information of stepper. I never knew such tool exist. reason I ended up this post was that I am so dissapointed with SfNumericUpdown. total disappointment with a lot of bugs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Stepper` for this:

XAML

```
<Stepper Value="5" 
         Minimum="0" 
         Maximum="10" 
         Increment="0.1" 
         HorizontalOptions="LayoutOptions.Center" 
         VerticalOptions="LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand"
         ValueChanged="OnValueChanged" />
```

---

C#

```
void OnValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e) {  
    lbldisp.Text = String.Format("Stepper value is {0:F1}", e.NewValue);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.stepper?view=xamarin-forms
maybe this could help. you might want to write a custom render for putting that textBox in between the -/+ buttons but sure if you can use as it is, it works fine.